# Compute lag difference for different days

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, datetime, subquery, lag

I need help computing a date difference across different rows with variable lag (specifically, rows that are not on the same day) without subqueries, joins, etc. I think this should be possible with some inline t-SQL aggregates that use `OVER(PARTITION BY)` clause, such as `LAG`, `DENSE_RANK`, etc., but I can't quite put a finger on it. This is for a SQL Server 2017 Developer's edition.

A clarifying example:

Consider a dataset with Job beginning and end dates (across various projects). Some jobs start and end on the same day (such as jobs 2 & 3, 4 & 5). I need to compute the idle time between consequent jobs that started on different days (per project). That is the days between last job's ending time and current job's beginning time. If the previous job started on the same day, then look further back in history of the same project. I.e. the jobs that started on the same day can be considered as parts of the same job.

UPDATE: I simplified the code/output by dropping time values (question's history has original dataset).

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#t') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #t; 
CREATE TABLE #t(Prj TINYINT, Beg DATE, Eñd DATE);
INSERT INTO #t SELECT 1, '1/1/17', '1/2/17';
INSERT INTO #t SELECT 1, '1/5/17', '1/7/17';
INSERT INTO #t SELECT 1, '1/5/17', '1/7/17';
INSERT INTO #t SELECT 1, '1/15/17', '1/15/17';
INSERT INTO #t SELECT 1, '1/15/17', '1/18/17';
INSERT INTO #t SELECT 1, '1/20/17', '1/24/17';
INSERT INTO #t SELECT 2, '2/2/17', '2/5/17';
INSERT INTO #t SELECT 2, '2/7/17', '2/9/17';
ALTER TABLE #t ADD Job INT NOT NULL IDENTITY (1,1) PRIMARY KEY;
```

A `LAG(.,1)` function uses precisely the previous job's ending time, which is not what I want. It yields incorrect idle duration for jobs 2 & 3, 4 & 5. Jobs 2 & 3 should both use the ending time of job 1. Jobs 4 & 5 should both use the ending time of job 3. The joined query computes idle duration correctly, but an inline calculation is desirable here (without joins, subqueries).

```
SELECT c.Job, c.Prj, c.Beg, c.Eñd, 
-- in-line computation with OVER clause
PrvEñd_lg=LAG(c.Eñd,1) OVER(PARTITION BY c.Prj ORDER BY c.Beg),
Idle_lg=DATEDIFF(DAY, LAG(c.Eñd,1) OVER(PARTITION BY c.Prj ORDER BY c.Beg), c.Beg),
-- calculation over current and (joined) previous records
PrvEñd_j=MAX(p.Eñd), 
IdleDur_j=DATEDIFF(DAY, MAX(p.Eñd), c.Beg)
FROM #t c LEFT JOIN #t p ON c.Prj=p.Prj AND c.Beg > p.Eñd
GROUP BY c.Job, c.Prj, c.Beg, c.Eñd
ORDER BY c.Prj, c.Beg


Job Prj Beg         Eñd         PrvEñd_lg   Idle_lg PrvEñd_j    IdleDur_j
1   1   2017-01-01  2017-01-02  NULL        NULL    NULL        NULL
2   1   2017-01-05  2017-01-07  2017-01-02  3       2017-01-02  3
3   1   2017-01-05  2017-01-07  2017-01-07  -2      2017-01-02  3
4   1   2017-01-15  2017-01-15  2017-01-07  8       2017-01-07  8
5   1   2017-01-15  2017-01-18  2017-01-15  0       2017-01-07  8
6   1   2017-01-20  2017-01-24  2017-01-18  2       2017-01-18  2
7   2   2017-02-02  2017-02-05  NULL        NULL    NULL        NULL
8   2   2017-02-07  2017-02-09  2017-02-05  2       2017-02-05  2
```

Please let me know, if I can further clarify any specific details.

Many thanks!

Comment: Joins, subqueries and CTEs are a fundamental part of SQL.  Learn to use and apply them correctly instead of trying to impose arbitrary restrictions on their use.  Trying to write SQL without using them is like trying to write client-code without using functions, methods or subroutines.  Of course you can do it, but there is no real good reason to not to, and it generally results in bad code and wasted time.  And if you are "*just seeking a challenge*" then you should be doing this yourself and not asking here because that's not a real programming question.

Comment: RBarryYoung: Yours are mostly true statements, but none answers my question :) The criticism is unfair, since you are not privy of the full context of my task. Your solution, if offered, is very welcome :) FYI: I have spent sufficient time on this and continue to try out ideas. In fact, please kindly notice my (`join`) solution too. This calculation is the only one that I was stuck on so far (others I solved efficiently). Agreeably, if I am to re-invent the wheel in everything, then why even have this forum? I'm here to help and, hopefully, you are too :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use a [`self-join`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177490(v=sql.105).aspx).

```
select a.Job
, a.Prj
, a.Beg
, a.Eñd
, max(b.Eñd) as PrevEñd
, min(datediff(mi, b.Eñd, a.Beg) / (60*24.0)) as IdleDur
from #t as a
left join #t as b on a.Prj = b.Prj
                 and cast(a.Beg as date) > cast(b.Eñd as date)
group by a.Job
, a.Prj
, a.Beg
, a.Eñd
```

This produces the following output:

```
+-----+-----+---------------------+---------------------+---------------------+-----------+
| Job | Prj |         Beg         |         Eñd         |       PrevEñd       |  IdleDur  |
+-----+-----+---------------------+---------------------+---------------------+-----------+
|   1 |   1 | 2017-01-01 01:00:00 | 2017-01-02 02:00:00 | NULL                | NULL      |
|   2 |   1 | 2017-01-05 02:00:00 | 2017-01-07 03:00:00 | 2017-01-02 02:00:00 | 3.0000000 |
|   3 |   1 | 2017-01-05 03:00:00 | 2017-01-07 02:00:00 | 2017-01-02 02:00:00 | 3.0416666 |
|   4 |   1 | 2017-01-15 04:00:00 | 2017-01-15 03:00:00 | 2017-01-07 03:00:00 | 8.0416666 |
|   5 |   1 | 2017-01-15 15:00:00 | 2017-01-18 03:00:00 | 2017-01-07 03:00:00 | 8.5000000 |
|   6 |   1 | 2017-01-20 05:00:00 | 2017-01-24 02:00:00 | 2017-01-18 03:00:00 | 2.0833333 |
|   7 |   2 | 2017-02-02 06:00:00 | 2017-02-05 03:00:00 | NULL                | NULL      |
|   8 |   2 | 2017-02-07 07:00:00 | 2017-02-09 02:00:00 | 2017-02-05 03:00:00 | 2.1666666 |
+-----+-----+---------------------+---------------------+---------------------+-----------+
```

Comment: Thanks. That's exactly the example I posted :) I'm looking for an inline solution without joins, subqueries.

Comment: Seems there have been a lot of changes to the question after my answer was posted. Do you mind updating the question with an explanation of why you're trying to avoid the use of joins/subqueries? Might help me (or others) help you.

Comment: Hi Tarheel. The core question has not changed (see history). I dropped time values to simplify the question :) Thanks for the suggestion, I added clarification about the avoidance of join/subquery to the question's body. Btw, how do you print out the results in a table form? Is it SQL Server's built-in feature or a manual formatting? It's nice.