# t-SQL: calculate date difference with dynamic lag

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, lag, over-clause

Is there a way to compute the duration between consequent dates that are not the same, **using SQL Server 2017's `OVER` clause** and without joins or subqueries? Could this possibly be done with a `LAG` function using some dynamically computed lag argument?

For example, trx 2 & 3 are on the same day, so we compute the duration from 1 to 2 and from 1 to 3. Since 4 occurred on a different day, its duration is from  3 to 4. Since trx 5 is on the same day as 4, we compute its duration from 3 to 5 and so on.

```
CREATE TABLE #t(Trx TINYINT, DT DATE);
INSERT INTO #t SELECT 1, '1/1/17';
INSERT INTO #t SELECT 2, '1/5/17';
INSERT INTO #t SELECT 3, '1/5/17';
INSERT INTO #t SELECT 4, '1/15/17';
INSERT INTO #t SELECT 5, '1/15/17';
INSERT INTO #t SELECT 6, '1/20/17';
```

Below is an easy implementation with a join, but can this be done inline with some `OVER` clause function (no join or subqueries)?

```
SELECT c.Trx, c.DT, 
DurO=DATEDIFF(DAY, LAG(c.DT,1) OVER(ORDER BY c.DT), c.DT), -- does not use join
DurJ=DATEDIFF(DAY, MAX(p.DT), c.DT) -- uses join
FROM #t c LEFT JOIN #t p ON c.DT > p.DT
GROUP BY c.Trx, c.DT
ORDER BY c.DT
```

Note that `DurJ` is computed correctly, but `DurO` is not:

```
Trx DT          DurO    DurJ
1   2017-01-01  NULL    NULL
2   2017-01-05  4       4
3   2017-01-05  0       4
4   2017-01-15  10      10
5   2017-01-15  0       10
6   2017-01-20  5       5
```

I'll clarify further any specifics, if needed.

NOTE: Not a dup question. This question is concerned with one date column only and no project grouping. Btw, neither question has a satisfiable solution just yet.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Compute lag difference for different days](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47720899/compute-lag-difference-for-different-days)

Answer (score 2):

Use `dense_rank` to treat same dates as one group and use it to get the same difference.

```
select trx,beg,sum(diff) over(partition by grp) as diff
from (select trx,beg,datediff(day,lag(beg) over(order by beg),beg) as diff,
      dense_rank() over(order by beg) as grp
      from #t
     ) t
```

Per @Alexey's comment's, dense_rank isn't actually needed. You can just use `beg` date for grouping.

```
select trx,beg,sum(diff) over(partition by beg) as diff
from (select trx,beg,datediff(day,lag(beg) over(order by beg),beg) as diff
      from #t 
     ) t
```

Comment: Is it really needed to partition by dense_rank for sum(diff)? Wouldn't it work too if to partition just by date instead?

Comment: @Alexey .. you are right..edited it into the answer.

Comment: Thanks Vamsi and Alexey for an interesting solution. Can the calculation be done inline, i.e. directly from `#t` with some `OVER` clause and without subqueries or joins?